# Shaving in Honor of Shabbos During Sefirah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sefirat-ha-omer, shaving

I was wondering if any of the Poskim deal with whether one can shave his beard in honor of Shabbos during Sefirah. Do they?

As always, please cite your sources.

Comment: Can you indicate why you might think one couldn't? Can you indicate why you think one could?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no reason to think either way. That's way I posted the question....

Comment: That's a terrible reason to post a question.

Comment: From the Stam Shulchan Aruch it seems assur,but there are those who have a heter.

Comment: See [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/shavuot/sefiratha-omer3.htm) and [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/shavuot/20shavin.htm) for discussion of this question.

Comment: They Say the Chafetz Chaim permitted it on erev Shabbos if u normally shave twice a week.

Comment: @user4784 See *Mishna B'rura* (551:32) and *Bi'ur Halacha* (ibid. s.v. וכן לכבוד שבת) regarding haircuts. Perhaps you can draw an inference from there that shaving is permitted if normally done on a weekly basis.

Comment: It's common for Sepharadim to shave every week in honor of Shabbat and they continue to do this during the Omer.  Walking into most Sephardic shuls and you'll see most of the men clean shaven on erev Shabbat.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on the 31st or 33rd or 45th or 47th or 48th of the *omer*, according to various opinions cited in [*Nit'e Gavriel*, *Pesach* volume 3, chapter 49, paragraphs 22–29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&pgnum=285).